# Comparing and moving fields in excel

Tags: excel, compare, excel-formula

I have a strange question that i hope someone could help me with. I have a list of items in column A and have another list of items in column D. These are mostly identical there are just a few more items in Column B.

```
Column A     Column B    Column C          Column D
1015          1015          $25               $5
1025          1035          $25               $5
1035          1045          $25               $5
1045          1055          $25               $5
```

Ok so what i would like to do is Use the items in the column A and compare then to column B.

Then i would like to move the rows from B-D down, so that D is next to A and has the same skus.

```
Column A     Column B    Column C          Column D
1015          1015          $25               $5
1025          
1035          1035          $25               $5
1045          1045          $25               $5
```

Please Help! Thank you very much!!!

Comment: You are looking for a Formula to do this? Or do you want this to be done in VBA. In either case could you show us what have you tried and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no unmatched values exist in the column B.

For VBA solution try this:

```
Sub MatchRows()
  Dim sheet As Worksheet
  Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

  'First Column
  Dim rngA As Range
  Set rngA = [A1:A10]
  Dim datA As Variant
  datA = rngA
  Dim i As Long

  'Second Column Match
  Dim rngB As Range
  Set rngB = [B1:B10]
  Dim datB As Variant
  datB = rngB
  Dim j As Long

  'Store duplicates
  Dim rngString As String

  'First Column loop
  For i = LBound(datA, 1) To UBound(datA, 1)
    'Second Column Loop
    For j = LBound(datB, 1) To UBound(datB, 1)
        'Check if duplicate
        If datA(i, 1) = datB(j, 1) And i <> j And Not IsEmpty(datB(j, 1)) And Not IsEmpty(datA(i, 1)) Then
            Dim rng As String
            rng = Chr(rngB.Column + 64) & j & ":" & Chr(rngB.Column + 64 + 2) & j
            Range(rng).Select

            For k = 1 To (i - j)
                Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            Next
        End If
      Next
  Next
End Sub
```

Note that I hard coded the ranges and the offset value (+2) for the number of columns to push down.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your input is on Sheet1. Then copy the following formulas in a new sheet to the cells

```
A1: =Sheet1!A1
B1: =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1;Sheet1!$B$1:$D$4;1;FALSE);"")
C1: =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1;Sheet1!$B$1:$D$4;2;FALSE);"")
D1: =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1;Sheet1!$B$1:$D$4;3;FALSE);"")
```

and then copy the first row to rows 2, 3 and 4.